# How to handle import error in sas db and go to a next import?

Tags: excel, import, sas

Hi I wanted to introduce error handling in a macro, that imports multiple excel files:

```
%macro ReadIn(input = , output = );

    proc import datafile = "&input."
                dbms = xlsx
                out = &output._input
                replace;
                sheet = "Sheet1";
    run;

    DATA oridata;
       SET &output._input;
       format _all_;
    RUN;

    (... further data modification...)
%mend;
```

And this produces sas databases for countries (Country1, Country2...) . However, when the import is not successful, incited of a country database being empty, sas seem to copy paste database from previous import.

Later on I aggregate those sas databases to have one final database and so I see dupplicates.

Is it possible to enter:

```
%macro ReadIn(input = , output = );

    proc import datafile = "&input."
                dbms = xlsx
                out = &output._input
                replace;
                sheet = "Sheet1";
    run;




if &output._input Empty, then next;

or 

if &output._input Empty, then &output._input = 0;


    DATA oridata;
       SET &output._input;
       format _all_;
    RUN;

    (... further data modification...)
%mend;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of observations by opening the file and reading its observation count with the following code:

```
%let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&output._input));
%let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid., nlobs));
%let rc   = %sysfunc(close(&dsid.));
```

Now you can use the macro variable `&nobs` to check how many observations were read in. We'll only run the data modification code if the number of observations is greater than 0.

```
%macro ReadIn(input = , output = );

    proc import datafile = "&input."
                dbms = xlsx
                out = &output._input
                replace;
                sheet = "Sheet1";
    run;

    %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&output._input));
    %let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid., nlobs));
    %let rc   = %sysfunc(close(&dsid.));

    %if(&nobs. > 0) %then %do;

        DATA oridata;
           SET &output._input;
           format _all_;
        RUN;

        (... further data modification...)
    %end;
    
%mend;
```

You'll create these code blocks for every dataset you want to conditionally import and modify.

Checking the number of observations in a dataset is a fairly common operation. You can simplify this further by making it a macro that returns the number of observations:

```
%macro nobs(data);
    %if(%sysfunc(exist(&data.))) %then %do;
        %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&data.));
        %let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid., nlobs));
        %let rc   = %sysfunc(close(&dsid.));
    %end;
        %else %let nobs = -1;
    
    &nobs.
%mend;
```

Example:

```
%put The number of obs in sashelp.cars is %nobs(sashelp.cars);
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern might help.  Delete the target out= data set before the Proc IMPORT.   Perform conditional processing after the IMPORT based on EXIST().

Example:

```
%if %sysfunc(exist(&output._input)) %then %do;
  proc delete data=&output._input
%end;

PROC IMPORT .... out=&output._input ...;
run;

%if %sysfunc(exist(&output._input)) %then %do;
...
%end;
```